# Mock axios get request returning back undefined response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

My jest test mock of an axios get returns back `undefined` as the response and I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

My component that has the axios call is shown below:

```
import {AgGridReact} from "ag-grid-react";
import React, {useEffect, useState, useMemo} from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
  if(searchObject)
    console.log("new being fetched")
  fetchResults(gridApi);
}, [searchObject]);

const fetchResults = (paramsApi) => {
  Service()
  .getResults(searchObject)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("calling.....", response); // undefined for response, why?
    let results = response.data.results;
    // more code below but unnecessary to show since response is undefined
```

---

Jest test class:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { screen } from '@testing-library/dom';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import AgGridResults from "./AgGridResults";

describe('AgGridResults', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    jest.mock("../../service/Service", () => ({
      __esModule: true,
      default: () => ({
        getResults: async () => ({
          data: { results: { M0: { value: ["Source ID"] } } },
        }),
      }),
    }));
    render(<AgGridResults searchObject={...} />);
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText('Actions')).toBeInTheDocument())
  });

  test('AgGridResults', () => {
    expect(screen.getByText('Actions')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

---

```
import axios from 'axios';
import UrlUtility from './urlUtility';

function Service() {
  return {
    getResults: async (searchObject) => {
      let urlString = UrlUtility().convert(searchObject);
      if (searchObject && urlString) {
        return await axios.get('/api/' + urlString + '&pageLength=50');
      }
    },
    getAgreementTypes: async (searchTerm) => {
      return await axios.get('/api/' + 'searchString=' + searchTerm);
    },
  };
}

export default Service;
```

Comment: Your component doesn't appear to use Axios anywhere. Seems to me you should be mocking `Service().getResults()` (whatever that is)

Comment: @Phil Service is just `return await axios.get('/api?' + searchTerm);`

Comment: Can't be because then you'd get an error saying `getResults` is not a function. In any case, if your component uses `Service`, I'd recommend you mock `Service`. If you really want to continue with mocking out transitive dependencies like Axios, please [edit] your question to include the `Service` definition

Comment: @Phil I have included my service call

Comment: Why are you mixing ES imports with CJS `require()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking Axios when your component doesn't actually use it creates a brittle coupling. If you ever changed the `Service` implementation, your tests would break.

I would instead mock `Service` for your component test

```js
jest.mock("./path/to/service", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => ({
    getResults: async () => ({
      data: { results: { M0: { value: ["Source ID"] } } },
    }),
  }),
}));
```

Comment: I refactored to that but it still returns undefined for response.

Comment: @user21476047 Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77312733/edit) to show how `Service` is imported into your component. Please also include the full test file. It's still unclear why you're using `require()` in the test

Comment: I have included my imports. I removed the `require` since it is not needed anymore since i am mocking my service instead of the axios call

Comment: @user21476047 Mock modules should be declared at the top level, outside the `describe()`

Comment: ty it works now

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

describe('EcgDataProcessor (e2e)', () => {
  
  let axiosMock: any;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    axiosMock = new MockAdapter(axios);
    axiosMock.onGet('https://path').reply(200, "response");
  })
  
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter